# R Question: estimate the avg mark of students and place 95% bound on error of est and 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval

Take a single systematic sample of size 20 from a vector of length 300. Treating this sample as a SRS, estimate the average mark of students. Place a 95% bound on the error of estimation, and give a 95% confidence interval.

Would this work? (If my vector of length 300 is x). As well, I'm not sure if I've properly included an error bound of 95%.

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
s <- sample(x, n, replace = FALSE)
x_bar <- mean(s)
s2_x <- var(s)
b_sample <- 2*sqrt(s2_x)
con_int<- cbind(x_bar - b_sample, x_bar + b_sample)
con_int
```

Thanks!

Comment: NeilsonsMilk, welcome. (1) if your code in the answer below is your own resolution to the question and you need nobody else to comment, then all is fine; otherwise, it likely belongs in your question itself, please [edit] it and put it there instead (and delete your answer). (2) Homework is fine, but it is expected that you will do your research before coming here, demonstrating what you *think*; [help/on-topic] says *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."*

Comment: @r2evans thank you for your feedback. I've fixed my question

Comment: Isn't standard error typically related to the size of the sample? That is, the larger the sample, the narrower the error.